# What is best JavaScript practice for keeping class callbacks within a context / scope?

Tags: javascript, class, callback

[similar question here, but not fully answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032098/best-practices-for-callbacks-within-a-scope)

I am trying to put my web application inside a class for better encapsulation, so it may be better used as a plugin on other sites. But for events that need callbacks (mouseover, etc), they lose the context of the calling class object. The only solution I've found so far is to used JQuery's `$.proxy` method. I have created a simple example:

https://jsfiddle.net/swb909/dcad5m3b/

I would expect there to be a slightly more elegant native solution / strategy for this, but I cannot find one. What is the best practice for this?

Edit: Perhaps a better example would be a JQuery callback for an AJAX request, a Node.JS emit callback, or a setTimeout call - both all be out of the context / scope of the calling class object.

Comment: Can you provide an example of where you feel the context is lost?  It isn't entirely clear to me what aspect of the language you are bumping into.

Comment: If you remove the `$.proxy` methods from my example, it will stop working. The callbacks will not inherit the context of the calling function. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/swb909/h29aqmyg/ But I am more concerned with the overall practice of maintaining a context, as this problem applies to all callbacks from classes and things like setTimeout or Node.JS emit callbacks, etc

Comment: Why can't you use a closure in this case?

Comment: @Brad I did some research on closures and they seem to be pretty cool. They are more like my idea of a class. Here is my example program in a closure: https://jsfiddle.net/swb909/9gqc420v/  I am able to use JQuery bindings and setTimeout and the callbacks are aware of the class object's variables. This looks like a cleaner solution than $.proxy and bind. I would select this if posted as an answer. I am surprised there is not more of a clear consensus on what is the best practice for maintaining context in a class, but would seem to be it, unless anyone else has any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> The callbacks will not inherit the context of the calling function.
>   Example: http://jsfiddle.net/swb909/h29aqmyg But I am more concerned
>   with the overall practice of maintaining a context, as this problem
>   applies to all callbacks from classes and things like setTimeout or
>   Node.JS emit callbacks, etc

This depends on expected context with handler . Both `overBox` , `outBox` methods appear to use selector `$('#box')` to call `.css()` instead of `$(this)` ; `this` could be set to `hoverbox` to have access to `hoverbox` properties within event handler without affecting expected results.

Try utilizing [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
var hoverbox = function(id, overColor, outColor) {
    this.changeColors(overColor, outColor);
    $(id).mouseover(this.overBox.bind(this))
    $(id).mouseout(this.outBox.bind(this))
}

hoverbox.prototype.overBox = function (e) {
    console.log(e, this)
  $('#box').css('background', this.overBoxColor)
}

hoverbox.prototype.outBox = function () {
  $('#box').css('background', this.outBoxColor)
}

hoverbox.prototype.changeColors = function (overColor, outColor) {
    this.overBoxColor = overColor;
    this.outBoxColor = outColor;
    $('#box').css('background', outColor)
}

var hb = new hoverbox('#box', 'blue', 'red');

$('#changeColors1').click(function(){hb.changeColors('yellow', 'green')})
$('#changeColors2').click(function(){hb.changeColors('purple', 'orange')})
$('#changeColors3').click(function(){hb.changeColors('blue', 'red')})
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h29aqmyg/3/